# Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath with ant

Tags: java, ant, java-8

I am trying to run ant command but it's giving me error like this:

```
[javac] Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

I am pretty new to java/jdk. Please help what's wrong here. Thanks

Comment: I am using Centos 6.8

Comment: What is the value of your JAVA_HOME?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is /opt/zimbra/common/lib/jvm/java